# Cannot reinstall WhatsApp on Samsung Galaxy Note Pro

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, whatsapp-messenger, installation, tablet

I have installed WhatsApp on my Samsung Galaxy Note Pro previously but uninstalled it a few days later. Now that I want to install it back again, it says the device does not support WhatsApp.

Please advise why am I able to install at 1st and not now?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp provides the APK file to install without the Play Store.
The APK can be found here: http://www.whatsapp.com/android/

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more specific detail. Is the error warning appears on the Play Store or when you try to open WhatsApp? What Galaxy Note Pro do you use?

If you are using Galaxy Note Pro 12.2 WiFi only, based on this [WhatsApp FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/21166563), your device is unfortunately not supported.

Comment: The errors appear on playstore stating 'your device isn't compatible with this version.' The Note Pro I'm using is Galaxy Note Pro Model SM-P905. In fact I have downloaded whatsapp in this device when I bought it few days back.